# Springboot JWT: Authentication failed: no credentials provided

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

This is regarding Springboot security JWT authentication.

I am able to successfully generate a JWT token using `/login` but on calling one authenticated API endpoint with that generated token I am getting 401 unauthorized..

In logs I am getting `o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication failed: no credentials provided`

At code level I am able to debug till JwtAuthenticationFilter -> doFilterInternal -> 79 without any exception (checked adding 79 line inside try catch too) but the required controller is not being called.

**/login API:**
[image]

**Authenticated API call:**
[image]

**Security Config:**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/h2/**","/api/public/login")
        .permitAll()
        //.mvcMatchers("/api/auth/consumer/cart").hasRole("CONSUMER")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(apiAuthenticationEntryPoint);
        
        http
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

**Logs on calling authenticated API:**

[logs](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ityTAveb9XGMjQJS3oaiMy/0)

Comment: Please do not post images of code as it is against the rules of SO. Please read the rules before posting on SO